# Sales Cloud and Salesforce CPQ

Tags: licenses, sales-cloud, cpq

What is the difference Sales Cloud and Salesforce CPQ. Is there any difference in their licenses. Do sales cloud licience is enough to work on CPQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce CPQ is a separate product which requires purchase of additional licences from Salesforce. The list prices are shown [here](https://www.salesforce.com/products/quote-to-cash/pricing/), but as always with licencing talk to your Account Executive.

The Sales Cloud is included in the standard Salesforce CRM licence and the current pricing for it is [here](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/).